# Goto command after an echo

Tags: batch-file, goto

Is it possible to use a goto right after an echo without making a new line?

```
set /p talk=">"
if /i "%talk%"=="hello" echo Hello!
if /i "%talk%"=="how are you?" echo Good thanks!
if /i "%talk%"=="who are you?" echo I am COM.
echo That statement was not recognized.
goto 1
```

can I make it so that it goes to the start after it echos one of the response lines and if you misstype it says "That statement was not recognized." and goto 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to jump in batch:

- make a code block

```
    @ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
    :first
    set /p "talk=>"
    if /i "%talk%"=="hello" echo Hello!
    if /i "%talk%"=="how are you?" echo Good thanks!
    if /i "%talk%"=="who are you?" (
        echo I am COM.
        goto:first
    )
```

---

- connecting commands with an ampersand `&`

```
    @ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
    :first
    set /p "talk=>"
    if /i "%talk%"=="hello" echo Hello!
    if /i "%talk%"=="how are you?" echo Good thanks!
    if /i "%talk%"=="who are you?" echo I am COM. &goto:first
```

You need always a target jump label, eg. `:first`.

Comment: so if you put & it stops the echo?

Answer (score 0):

```
set /p talk=">"
if /i "%talk%"=="hello" echo Hello! & goto :skip_error
if /i "%talk%"=="how are you?" echo Good thanks! & goto :skip_error
if /i "%talk%"=="who are you?" echo I am COM. & goto :skip_error
echo That statement was not recognized.
goto 1
:skip_error
```